# Batch file to remove certain string from multiple files across multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos, mhtml

I have a folder with many subfolders each containing dozens of `.mht` files of different lengths. I need help creating a batch script to filter out this certain string:

```
"</BODY></HTML>"
```

I can the add lines of [html](/questions/tagged/html) to the file before adding it back to the end. This is what I have so far:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%a in (*.mht) do (
    for /f "skip=11" %%b in (%%a) do (if %%b=="</BODY></HTML>" del %%b)
    echo "stuff to add">>%%a
    echo "</BODY></HTML>">>%%a
)
```

Is there any way to fix my current script or perhaps any of you know any easier way to do this?

**Note**: I tried copying everything except the unwanted string to a temp file but first 11 lines contain special characters ex:`|  ,  .  :`

Comment: very related question, bordering on duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: @ebyrob Unfortunately, that question has no answers for batch.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann I thought BatchSubstitute.bat on dostips.com was a pure Batch solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I have added a new script which will replace the search term with the desired code right into the line.  The script can handle special characters.

---

### Limitations

1. Leading Close Bracket **`]`** characters will be trimmed from the beginning of lines.  Not an issue since there should be no lines in HTML beginning with this character. **(This can be fixed if needed)**
2. The percent sign **`%`** character cannot be used in either the search term or replacement term.

### Notes

1. Lines cannot contain an odd number of double quotations **`"`** so I double the double quotations **`""`** to ensure an even number.  This means that if you have quotations in either of the strings, they must as well be doubled!
2. To use the script, just replace the **search term** and **replacement term** with what you want on the following line of code.

   `set "_=%_:`**search term**`=`**replacement term**`%"`

### New Script.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:: Limitations
:: 1. Any leading close bracket ] characters will be trimmed due to delims=].

for /r %%F in (html.txt) do if exist "%%~fF" (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%K in ('type "%%~fF" ^| find /n /v ""') do (
        set "_=%%L"
        call :Expand_
    )
)
goto End


:Expand_
:: NULL is a blank line or line with only a close bracket ].
if not defined _ echo. & goto :eof
:: Ensure even number of double quotation marks.
set "_=%_:"=""%"
:: Inject the code.
set "_=%_:</body>=<code>To Inject</code></body>%"
:: Escape batch special characters.
set "_=%_:^=^^%"
set "_=%_:<=^<%"
set "_=%_:>=^>%"
set "_=%_:&=^&%"
set "_=%_:|=^|%"
:: Revert quotations.
set "_=%_:""="%"
:: Display
echo(%_%
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause >nul
```

---

### Original

This should do what you want.  No Delayed Expansion needed.  Should support all special characters.

### Limitations

1. Leading Close Bracket **`]`** characters will be trimmed.  Not an issue since there should be no lines in HTML beginning with the close bracket character.  **(This can be fixed if needed.)**
2. The percent sign **`%`** character cannot be used in either the search term or replacement term.

### Notes

1. Lines cannot contain an odd number of double quotations **`"`** so I double the double quotations **`""`** to ensure an even number.  This means that if you have quotations in the string to match, they must as well be doubled. **(Does not apply to your scenario)**
2. Delayed Expansion cannot be used around this line `for /f %%S in ('echo "%xLine%"^| find /i "</body>"') do (` else `!` exclamation marks will cause an issue.

### Script.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

for /r %%F in (*.mht) do if exist "%%~fF" (
    rem Limitation - Any leading close bracket ] characters will be trimmed.
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%K in ('type "%%~fF" ^| find /n /v ""') do (
        set "xLine="%%L""
        call :Match
        echo(%%L>>"%%~dpF\new_%%~nF%%~xF"
    )
    rem del "%%~fF"
    rem ren "%%~dpF\new_%%~nF%%~xF" "%%~nxF"
)
goto End


:Match
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Double the double quotations to ensure even number of double quotations.
set "xLine=%xLine:"=""%"
for /f %%S in ('echo "%xLine%"^| find /i "</body>"') do (
    rem Add your code to inject here.  Copy the template echo below.
    rem Note that special characters need to be escaped.
    echo Inject Code>>"%%~dpF\new_%%~nF%%~xF"
)
endlocal
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause >nul
```

This will output the new file to `new_<filename>.mht`  If you want to replace the old file with the new file, just remove the `rem` command from before the `del` and `ren` commands.

Comment: This is great. However In some of the files </BODY></HTML> is not the only thing on the last line of code eg some files end with <p>example</p></BODY></HTML>

Comment: @user1978045  I have updated my answer with a new script that should do what you want. **`:)`**